# Schwarz’s Proof for Schwarz’s Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, math-history

Recently，I read an article named “From Schwarz to Pick to Ahlfors and Beyond”, where it says that

> The standard proof (By Maximum Modulus Principle) of the Schwarz Lemma is not the proof that Schwarz himself originally gave.

So I want to know the original proof by Schwarz. However, I searched for it for a long time, but failed. Hence, I want to ask you for help, or you can give me another proof other than by maximum modulus principle.

Comment: I did some research, and I cannot find anything about an "original" *proof* by Schwarz; but I can find many sources that mention some "original Schwarz lemma". However, a lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(mathematics) is not a proof. Are you sure that you aren't misinterpreting the author? Or, perhaps, the author themselves has made a mistake.